# android - pass a toast from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-toast

Not sure if this will work or not but I am trying to send a toast message to RiderHome activity from CustomerCall activity.

Once the driver selects cancel. a toast needs to be sent to the RiderHome activity saying "The Driver has cancelled the request"

Can this be done?

**CustomerCall**

```
btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDecline);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                cancelBooking();
        }
    });

}

private void cancelBooking() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), RiderHome.class);
    String cancel = "cancel"
    intent.putExtra("cancel", cancel);
    startActivity(intent);

    Toast.makeText(CustomerCall.this, "The Driver has cancelled 
    the request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**RiderHome**

```
public class RiderHome extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

   }

}
```

Comment: How do you navigate RiderHome activity? Could you include your code snippet using intent?

Comment: Why don't you just toast on the CustomerCall Activity? Why do you need to pass a toast/message from another activity to another activity if you're just going to toast it?

Comment: @TentenPonce Once the driver cancels the request, a msg needs to be sent to the Rider that the request was cancelled

Comment: Do you mean on the other phone/application? Or is this just a single app because according to your title, from activity to activity.

Comment: @TentenPonce. I have one app where you can either log in as a driver or a rider.  If user is Driver and a user on another phone is Rider ...

Comment: Ok so it is on another phone, your question must be how can you send/receive data from your app real time, something like that. You can search for sockets, or Firebase push notification but instead of notification, you will generate a toast.

Comment: @HaiHack see edit in cancelBooking()

Comment: I'm not clear about what you said here, it seems you mentioned something about communication between 2 users using your app, not between 2 activities.

Comment: @HaiHack Yes I am new to this but I have one app with 2 users

Comment: @TentenPonce I found this: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html .. is this what you meant?

Comment: If you use intents, once the driver cancels the request, the driver will also be the one to receive the toast because you just passed the data on the app itself, it is not what you want to happen right? You want the driver (another person) using the same app, cancels it, the rider (another person) will receive it but still, the same app. Your question is a bit confusing. Refer to my answer a while ago, sockets and firebase.

Comment: you will need a database to communicate between drivers & riders. You will also need a separate database for your booking.  Whenever a Rider books a cab, you will save that to database with an active status, then you will retrieve those active bookings to your driver app. It will need a real time database to instantly show changes on your each apps. Try to use Firebase Real-time Database for this task. It will work perfectly fine.

Comment: @AshishGupta I am using Firebase and was using FCM for notifications but not working for me for some reason. Maybe because I have 2 apps in one?

Comment: @LizG have you added your google.json file inside your source folder. Your app should be in background for receiving notifications. Don't forget to add services in your manifest for Firebase Messaging.

Comment: Yup did all that

Comment: @LizG, you can use Notification HTTP Protocol for sending notification to one app to another app, using another app's Firebase Token. Here is the documentation for this: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)

Comment: @LizG this above protocol is used for interacting to apps like one to one chat. In this the notification data is pushed through HTTP request. To use this, you will need Firebase Token for both the apps.

Comment: @AshishGupta I did all that but the notifications wouldn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way-:

```
private void cancelBooking() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), RiderHome.class);
    String cancel = "cancel"
    intent.putExtra("user_cancelled",cancel);
    startActivity(intent);

    Toast.makeText(CustomerCall.this, "The Driver has cancelled 
    the request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

In this pass a string value that indicates driver cancelled the request

and in RiderHome Activity you can check if you are getting that value by-:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
intent.getExtras();

if(intent.hasExtra("user_cancelled"))
{

    You can print your toast here.

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but didn't work :/. Its an app with different users so maybe thats why its not working. I figured if I just pass a string,  If string is passed I could then print the toast.  No luck,

Comment: are you able to move to riderhome activity?

Comment: From the CustomerCall activity through an intent?

Comment: Yes is intent redirecting to riderhome activity through CustomerCall?

Comment: Yes it does in the same phone. I need it to go to the Rider app not inside the Driver app. I need to find a way to do this or make them separate apps

Comment: Yes in seprate apps it won't work you can study about contentproviders in android that might help

Comment: Is there any way you could show me how to do the content provider in the way of code ... I def am confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161471/discussion-between-lizg-and-shivam-oberoi).

Answer (score -1):

instead of (Toast with activity - Toast's life is dead when activity is finished)

```
Toast.makeText(CustomerCall.this, "The Driver has cancelled 
the request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to (Use Context!! It will survive)

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "The Driver has cancelled 
the request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```